# Display field from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, associations, rails-activerecord

I use this code to find object relation for a specific user

```
<%= @tt = recipient.camping_ids %> => give me an ID example [75]
<%= @ww = Camping.find(@tt) %> => give me the result below
```

My result

```
#<Camping id: 75, name: "camping truc", adresse: "Route de machin", code_postale: "11100", commune: "Maville"]
```

Now I want display name value "Camping Truc", so I tried

```
<%= @ww.name %>
```

But, I get an undefined method error...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ww` holds an array of records and not a single record. If you want to get the name of first camping, you can get it using

```
@ww.first.name
```

Or if you want all the camping names, you can loop through all the records.

```
<% @ww.each do |w| %>
  <%= w.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for pointing out. Updated my answer. I had a misconception about the return types of `find` and `where`

Comment: Thanks! Glad I was able to help.